# displaying button text into navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Sir,in my app i placed some buttons.When i clicked a particular button,it goes to the next view.In that view i placed a navigation bar.What i need is,the name of the button should be displayed on a navigation bar title.please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, from an `UIViewController`:

```
self.navigationItem.title = myButton.currentTitle;
```

Comment: Sir,I tried this but an error occurred...     self.navigationItem.title = mybutton.titlestring; i tried in this way,where i declared titlestring as an nsstring also i passed the particular button name to titlestring

Comment: specify exactly what kind of error you have. I suppose that you add `titlestring` to UIButton through the inheritance ? Show what type of specifiers you use in its `@property. `retain`, `copy`, `assign` ?

Comment: Sorry sir for late reply,@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titlestring;in this way i declared titlestring..when i click a specific button,the data of a particular category will be displayed.So i allocated memory to that view controller in a button action,in that i wrote,viewController.titlestring=@"title";so that the title will be displayed on a navigation bar and in a viewdidload i wrote,self.navigationItem.title = myButton.titlestring; tell me where i went wrong

Comment: for `NSString`s is better to specify `copy` rather than `retain`. What I can see is that you assign a value to `viewController.titlestring` but not to `myButton.titlestring`. So, if `myButton.titlestring` has an uninitialized value, your application could crash.